# how i get value from grid view column from searching with some value and select appropriate row in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have  data grid with 4 column  in first column radio button,second column vehicle no like below

```
radio button     Vehicle RTO No.     Status      Unit_Serial No.    
 rbutton            AP22Y-3426        Offline     13030010010010    
 rbutton            KA02 AA 4518      Offline     1403200010    
 rbutton            KA02 CN 3401      Offline     1403200012    
 rbutton            KA04 00 4534      Online      1403200004    
 rbutton            KA04 QW 5670      Offline     1403200011    
 rbutton            KA12 AA 3107      Offline     13030021010021    
 rbutton            KA16 s 7650       Offline     200035
```

now I am getting Vehicle RTO No. from another page i want search  that vehicle no  in  Vehicle RTO No. column and select radio button that appropriate  vehicle no

Comment: pls help me in this task....

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ for this. Without knowing some more about your layout and whatnot, this is the best I can give you. But it should give you a good start.

```
var row = gridView.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().First(c => c.Cells[1].Text == vehicleRto);

var rButton = row.FindControl("rbutton");
```

You'll also, of course, want to add in some error handling as you see so fit.

Comment: How so? What is this doing (or not doing) that is unexpected?

Comment: i am getting vehicle rto no  for example  KA04 00 4534  i don't know at what index position  so i want to search in  vehicle rto no and auto select radio button of the whole row select in page_load event

Comment: "radio button of the whole row." I don't understand. If you want the row, my first line does that. If you want the radio button, my second line does. What about this doesn't do what you want?

Comment: sorry   i am getting some vehicle no  from another page through QueryString .That vehicle  no search in data grid vehicle rto no column if have that vehicle no in vehicle rto no column auto select rbutton          in radio button  column beside the vehicle no

Comment: So why can't you just do `rButton.Selected = true;` after that line?

Comment: It is giving error this "Sequence contains no elements"